# Recyclerview doesn't retrieve data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have added data in firebase. All i have to do is get that data in recyclerview. i have done this many type, but this time it is not showing and i don't know the reason because it is not showing in log. Can any one help?

here's my Activity where the RV is located
rvsalonlist is recyclerview

```
public void firebasedata() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<salonList> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<salonList>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("salon"), salonList.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new SalonListAdapter(options);
        rvSalonList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();

    }
```

This is the adapter

```
public class SalonListAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<salonList,SalonListAdapter.myviewholder> {


    public SalonListAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<salonList> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull salonList model) {
        holder.tvSalonName.setText(String.valueOf(model.getSalonName()));
        holder.tvSalonAddress.setText(String.valueOf(model.getSalonAddresss()));
        Glide.with(holder.ivSalonImage.getContext()).load(model.getImageUrl()).into(holder.ivSalonImage);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_salon,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView ivSalonImage;
        TextView tvSalonName, tvSalonMobileNumber, tvSalonAddress;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ivSalonImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSalonImage);
            tvSalonName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalonName);
            tvSalonMobileNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalonMobileNumber);
            tvSalonAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalonAddress);
        }
    }

}
```

Heres the model class .

```
[![public class salonList {

    private String imageUrl, salonName, ownerName, salonEmail, salonMobileNumber, salonAddresss, salonOpenTime, salonCloseTime;

    public salonList() {

    }

    public salonList(String imageUrl, String salonName, String ownerName, String salonEmail, String salonMobileNumber, String salonAddresss, String salonOpenTime, String salonCloseTime) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.salonName = salonName;
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
        this.salonEmail = salonEmail;
        this.salonMobileNumber = salonMobileNumber;
        this.salonAddresss = salonAddresss;
        this.salonOpenTime = salonOpenTime;
        this.salonCloseTime = salonCloseTime;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getSalonName() {
        return salonName;
    }

    public void setSalonName(String salonName) {
        this.salonName = salonName;
    }

    public String getOwnerName() {
        return ownerName;
    }

    public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
    }

    public String getSalonEmail() {
        return salonEmail;
    }

    public void setSalonEmail(String salonEmail) {
        this.salonEmail = salonEmail;
    }

    public String getSalonMobileNumber() {
        return salonMobileNumber;
    }

    public void setSalonMobileNumber(String salonMobileNumber) {
        this.salonMobileNumber = salonMobileNumber;
    }

    public String getSalonAddresss() {
        return salonAddresss;
    }

    public void setSalonAddresss(String salonAddresss) {
        this.salonAddresss = salonAddresss;
    }

    public String getSalonOpenTime() {
        return salonOpenTime;
    }

    public void setSalonOpenTime(String salonOpenTime) {
        this.salonOpenTime = salonOpenTime;
    }

    public String getSalonCloseTime() {
        return salonCloseTime;
    }

    public void setSalonCloseTime(String salonCloseTime) {
        this.salonCloseTime = salonCloseTime;
    }
}
```

Database Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your model class variable names and firebase attributes name are not same. use same name in both places.
for example in firebase use **salonName** instead of name. similarly for other attributes as well

Answer (score 1):

The names have to be identical
For eg, you have `ownerName` in the class but `ownername` in the database. Those should all be identical to the ones you have in your class.